# Is possible to add a converter to a annotation

Tags: java

Is possible to add a converter information to annotation.

My basic needs is to pick up AccessibleObject call Annotation.converter().convert(object)

Below example is simplified with object.toString() but can be more complex.

```
public interface MyConverter {
    default convert(Object o) {
        return o.toString()
    }
}

@interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<MyConverter> converter() default MyConverter.class
}


class Foo {
    public convert(AccessibleObject a) {
       //Convert doesn't because it is a class, but how to get the default method convert from the annotation setup?
        a.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).converter().convert(a)
    }

}
```

It would have been nice, if it was possible to setup Function<String, Object>

Comment: Get a `Constructor` from the `Class`, then call `newInstance(...)` to create an instance of the converter implementation. Once you have that instance, you can simply call `convert(...)` on it. Though note using `MyConverter` as the default value is problematic; it is an `interface`, which cannot be instantiated. You need to specify an _implementation_ of the interface.

Comment: Make sure to meta-annotate your `MyAnnotation` with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` if you want to be able to access it at run-time via reflection.

Comment: As for creating a `Function<Object, String>` for this, that's possible. Just create an implementation that uses the reflection under-the-hood. Or, if you're feeling brave and have good reasons, you can try to generate classes at run-time (e.g., via `LambdaMetafactory`). Though I really don't see how that would be beneficial in your case. Once you have the `MyConverter` instance, that is already a `Function<Object, String>` in all but name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation values have to be compile time constants. That's why you have to use a `Class` instead of an instance of that class.

You can create an instance from a `Class` object using the `newInstance` method. Make sure the class has a no-args constructor.

Comment: I thought so :( 
Tried to look through for example JsonDeserialize it seems like that as well.

Comment: @Dasma Just to note, [`Class#newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) has been deprecated since Java 9. See the deprecation description for the replacement code.

Comment: @Slaw thank you, I am using the getConstructor().newInstance() which is not deprecated :) But I don't like calling newInstance in general.

Comment: @Dasma Unfortunately, annotations are inherently based upon reflection (at least when processing them at run-time).